# Getting inline block elements to take up all white space

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

I am trying to stack elements on top of each other. In my situation I have elements with different heights that leads to unwanted white space.

I am looking for 6 and 7 boxes to move up with all corresponding elements under them.

```
.blockParent {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    left: 5%;
}

.block {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.smaller {
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

<div class="blockParent">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block smaller">
    </div>
    <div class="block smaller">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block ">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>

</div>
```

Results in this:
[image]

I think flexbox might be a solution but I have no experience with flexbox.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox wasn't designed to solve that. You can use CSS multi-columns instead. Note, the display order changes from horizontal to vertical.

```css
.blockParent {
  column-count: 3;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: silver;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.smaller {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockParent">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block smaller"></div>
  <div class="block smaller"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block "></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great that worked! Thank you for the help! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.blockParent {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
      /* left: 5%; */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blockParent">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block smaller">
    </div>
    <div class="block smaller">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block ">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
</div>

https://s.codepen.io/fasiya656/debug/NOrNQN/XxkVwaPeaooM
```

Comment: Please don't expect us to play spot-the-difference. Your answer should contain an explanation of what you've done to answer the question, not just a code dump.